# Use Magic Device and the Shield of the Mage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, skills

I am here for some clarification on what things I could do with Use Magic Device (through [Emulate Class Feature](https://www.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Use%20Magic%20Device)) to get the spell I want to appear on the [Shield of the Mage](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicIntelligentDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Shield%20of%20the%20Mage). I am fully aware that this is cartoon moon levels of cheese but it's for a one shot and the gm doesn't care.

Lets go from most specific to least:

1. Could you replicate a single spell known (a wizard with a single spell in his book)?
2. Could you replicate domains/bloodlines/mysteries for a small pool of spells known?
3. Could you replicate all wizard spells by replicating a wizard with a full book?
4. What abilities are there (like spell blending) to replicate that could give you a single spell?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Note that we generally have a policy of one question per post; I'm not an expert on Pathfinder, but it seems like there are multiple distinct questions in this post with very different answers. You should ask them separately; there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

**Could you replicate a single spell known (a wizard with a single spell in his book)?**

You cannot. Because *"ability to cast a specific spell"* is not one of wizard's class abilities. They have the ability to cast arcane spells, and any item requiring you to be *able to cast arcane spells* can be tricked using UMD.

If the requirement is *"able to cast Fireball"*, then all you have to do is to emulate that you are a 5th level wizard (a DC 25 check), which are all able to cast *Fireball*, and you would trick the item just fine.

**Could you replicate domains/bloodlines/mysteries for a small pool of spells known**

You can trick the item saying that you are a Rakshasa Sorcerer, or Conjurer Wizard, or a Cleric with the Fire Domain, or even that you have a certain archetype such as Hexblade Magus. You may also trick the item saying that you do have a list of *Spells Known*. And any spell added from a bloodline, domain, mystery, or similar class feature, is automatically added to your class's spell list, as [noted by Sean K. Reynolds](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mzdz?Scrolls-and-Domains#14) (ex-developer).

But you may not trick the item into saying that you *known Fireball* because that's not a class feature of those classes.

**Could you replicate all wizard spells by replicating a wizard with a full book?**

No, owning a spell book, or requiring one to cast spells is not a class feature. It is a limitation on preparing spells imposed on wizards, witches (through their familiar) and arcanists. But not a class ability *per se*. If the item asks for a *"prepared caster"* or *"cast spells like a wizard"*, then you may emulate that ability by saying you are a wizard ([Harry](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WTMf9aioYnQ/hqdefault.jpg)).

**What abilities are there (like spell blending) to replicate that could give you a single spell?**

If a class has the ability to cast a specific spell, then you may emulate that class ability. But as [noted by James Jacobs](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=410?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#20467) (Creative Director) before, UMD does not let you *use* that class ability, you simply bypass the item's requirement for that ability:

> *Over at the PFS section there is some confusion on how the UMD Skill works in regards to emulating a class. The question was targeted at Ring of Revelation. The argument is can a non-oracle utilize the ring to gain temporary access to a revelation with a sufficient roll of UMD? Some argue that no, you have to be an Oracle, and if you're not UMD won't help you. Others say that UMD circumvents those standard preventions.*
>
> Use Magic Device will let you trick an item into thinking you're a different class... but **it does not grant the POWERS of that class**. The way the ring of revelation is worded pretty much means you HAVE to be an Oracle (aka you have to meet minimum level requirements in class abilities granted by the oracle class, since the powers granted directly affect that ability rather than grant you NEW abilities). Furthermore, the ring specifically says that it has no effect if worn by a non-oracle.
>
> So. Best case scenario, you could Use Magic Device to trick the ring into activating, but if you don't actually have class levels in oracle, the ring will do nothing more than take up a ring slot for you.

Which is also noted on the description of [UMD](https://www.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Use%20Magic%20Device):

> This skill does not let you actually use the class feature of another class.

What is important to keep in mind here is that you do not *replicate* class abilities, you trick the item into thinking that you are a member of that class, or that you have that class ability, which is better worded as *emulate*, instead of *replicate*.

### Conclusion

You may cast whatever spell is on the scroll (using UMD), and you may even scribe a scroll later on it (since it is still a [Caster's Shield](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Caster%27s%20Shield)), but it won't wont randomly replace the spell cast on the scroll unless you are actually a caster, since you don't actually *know* any spells and that's not a requirement to use the shield, it's part of the shield's effect.

Comment: The wizard on the class feature [spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/) says, "A wizard may know any number of spells. He must choose and prepare his spells ahead of time by getting 8 hours of sleep and spending 1 hour studying his spellbook. While studying, the wizard decides which spells to prepare." The strong implication is that—despite the absence of a class feature named Spells Known or a table saying Spells Known—a wizard nontheless knows the spells in his or her spellbook. (I think we've had this debate before; if we have—or, y'know, haven't—ignore me. `:-)`)

Comment: We had, and you are correct. I will adjust that.

Comment: So... what's the bottom line on what you can and can't do with the shield?

Comment: You may cast whatever spell is on the scroll, and you may even scribe a scroll later on it (since it is still a Caster's Shield), but it wont randomly replace the spell cast unless you are actually a caster.

Comment: Im confused about the way you interpret emulating a class feature because as far as i read im not using the ability emulated, only making the shield think i have it. The ability says it lets you activate items as if you had that class feature. I would classify having the spell replaced by a spell you know as being the only thing about the shield itself you activate, And that knowing a spell is a class ability. If the specific ones referenced are the wrong ones then that is my bad, but they seemed to be the right ones as all i can find points to a wizard knowing the spells in his spellbook.

Comment: It falls into the same situation of the ring of revelations the way I see it, you dont actually have the ability, so the shield cannot scribe one of your known spells.

Comment: The rig of revellation is a bad comparison in the first place. The ring of revelations fails because you cant use what you are given access to(think doomharp)whereas the shield you are only triggering a power the shield inherently has(think Horn of the Huntsman(only the daze part))

Comment: I honestly see no difference in saying *Im a battle oracle, let me use this revelation* and *Im a wizard with Fireball known, let me scribe this on my shield*. Both are using abilities they dont really have.

Comment: The difference is im not the one scribing, im not using an ability. The shield is checking if i have an ability and then scribing itself(intelligent item and all that) to quote the text "This caster’s shield always has one arcane scroll *and knows the same arcane spells as the wielder*. When the spell on the scroll is cast, another scroll of a spell the wielder knows randomly *manifests to replace it*. At no point am i using an ability.

Comment: And why couldnt you use UMD to emulate that you do? That's my point.

Comment: The shield scribes a spell because *it knows the same arcane spells as the wielder*, you know no spell.

Comment: Try to imagine the conversation between wielder and shield: "Hey, im a wizard", "Sure", "Cast Fireball", "Sure", "Now scribe Invisibility" "Sure....But, how invisibility works again?"

Comment: The ring of revelation doesnt work is because you dont have the mystery from which you get the revellation. And the revelation class ability states "Revelation : at 1st level, 3rd level, and every four levels thereafter (7th, 11th, and so on), *an oracle uncovers a new secret about her mystery that grants her powers and abilities*." Clearly meaning its not separate from the mystery ability(think cantrips are bound to spellcasting)

Comment: (umd)"hey i know invisibility" "cool i know it too"(since it automatically also knows what i "know") bam, spell appears.

Comment: It never asks me how to scribe it, thats its own thing it does by itself. And im pretty sure it doent scribe, it manifests(means appear). Appearing doent really mean scribing

Comment: You still dont convince me that you actually *know* any spells. The post from James Jacobs is fairly clear to be that you cannot actually use anything emulated by UMD. But maybe you will have better luck with your GM.

Comment: Regardless, this is not a forum, so you should take that discussion to a messageboard. Comments are for improving and correcting an answer, not discussing if you like it or not.

Comment: I dont need to know, the shield needs to think i know. Because the shield knows all i know(or with umd all i make it think i know). And honestly it doesnt matter what it knows, or what i do because the knowing and manifesting are separate abilities. And the shield will manifest a random spell i know(or it thinks i know with umd). But i agree, this is not a discussion either of us should spend more time on, have a good day/night/whatever it happens to be.